# Ease into scrolling to anchor links?

Tags: jquery

I am using this piece of jquery that finds any anchor links on the page and lets me scroll to them. It works really well but I'm trying to figure out how I can make the scrolling ease in and out of the scroll.

Thanks.

```
//Scroll to anchors
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top -100
        }, 1000);
    }

    //end of scroll code
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `animate()` takes a timing function as an argument

The syntax is

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

So you can add

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top -100
    }, 1500, "swing");
```

By default it is `swing` which progresses slightly slower at the beginning and end of the animation than it does in the middle of the animation much like ease in and out. Then there is `linear` which progresses at a constant pace throughout the animation.

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top -100
    }, 1500, "linear");
```

You can also try increasing the duration to soften up the easing transition.

Comment: Thanks for this but for some reason when I add either linear or swing the code stops working.

Comment: @JulianJ Can you add a snippet or a fiddle for the issue!

Comment: I've made a fiddle for this here. As you can see with swing the animation does not work but if I remove swing it does work.: https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/9hw6bedL/3/

Comment: @JulianJ Sorry about that, I made some small mistakes in my code. Firstly the timing function argument should be passed as a string, and secondly it should come after the duration argument. Updated the code with the corrections.

Comment: That's great, works really well. Thank you.! ( I think there is a stray comma in your linear example - }, 1500, , "linear");

Comment: @JulianJ You can add other timing functions by including this [plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)